# How to set NULL for IntegerField instead of setting 0?

Tags: python, django, django-models, xlrd

I'm uploading some data from an excel file using xlrd and turning that data into models (with mainly IntegerField values) in Django. My excel file has a bunch of missing data. Unfortunately, these missing data are converted to the value of 0 in my models, instead of NULL. This means that when my Person model doesn't have an age, that age gets recorded as 0, instead of as NULL.

What's the best way to change this? I've tried doing this:

```
age = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

But the blank fields still get set to 0 by default.

Comment: do you have a default specified in your form ?

Comment: what is your database backend?

Comment: DB backend is MySQL. Don't have a default set. Should I do something like models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=NULL)?

Comment: Not default=NULL, default=None instead. Try that.

Comment: Hmm, getting the same problem even after default=None. Any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have `blank=True`? Are you planning to show it in a form?

Comment: hmm, that's probably unnecessary. Will get rid of it.

Comment: `null=True` will only matter if it's a blank string, not `0`. In your script why not have `age = age if not 0 else ''`. With `yourModel.age = age`, if it's an empty string it will be saved in your db as `NULL` as [shown here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null)

Comment: Did you do run a `syncdb` or schema migration after making the changes to the model?

Comment: Yeah, I actually dropped the table in question and re-ran the initial migration with South.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Instead of using

```
age = models.IntegerField()
```

use

```
age = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

When we specify

```
blank=True, null=True
```

it will allow you to store null in that column

Comment: I am doing this and trying to retrieve the data of the integer field on an android app, where it shows up as 0. Is this an ORM problem or is it transmitted as 0?

Comment: I don't think this is ORM problem. Does your schema has a default value set to 0?

Comment: This is backwards - specifying null=True *allows* NULL to be stored in the column.

Comment: Can we set the default value for `IntergerField` to null or for it to be null we shouldn't pass any value at all?