# How do I create a multiple filter in django-views?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Views:

```
def home(request):
     terminate = Tvserie.objects.filter(status='Terminata' or status='Cancellata').order_by('?')[0:4]

     return render_to_response('Home.html',{'terminate':terminate})
```

It is an error, why?
How do I create a multiple filter of the attribute "status"?

Models:

```
class Tvserie(models.Model):
      status_choices = (('Non iniziata', 'Non iniziata'),('In corso', 'In corso'),
                        ('In pausa', 'In pausa'),('Rinnovata', 'Rinnovata'),
                        ('Cancellata', 'Cancellata'),('Terminata', 'Terminata'))
      status = models.CharField(max_length = 30, choices=status_choices)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in`:

```
 terminate = Tvserie.objects.filter(status__in=['Terminata''Cancellata']).order_by('?')[0:4]
```

Comment: another question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686089/how-can-i-save-the-data-even-if-their-value-in-a-form-is-null

Comment: This answer may help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527308/how-to-set-null-for-integerfield-instead-of-setting-0

Answer (score -1):

Here is the answer to your question :)

[Q objects](http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2011/jun/14/best-way-or-list-django-orm-q-objects/)

Instead of passing explicit parameter you want to be used in filtering, you pass a `Q object` that encapsulates such information. Moreover, you can use `|` and `&` operators to join them by `or` and `and` operators.

In your case, it would look like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

terminate = Tvserie.objects.filter(Q(status='Terminata') | Q(status='Cancellata')).order_by('?')[0:4]
```