# How can I save the data even if their value in a form is null?

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

If I not complete the form for "annoinizio" or "annofine" or "stagioni" or "totepisodi" django plays form.is_valid() and returns False.
How can I save the data even if their value is null?

Models:

```html
class Tvserie(models.Model):
        titolo = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
        titolo_originale = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
        annoinizio = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
        annofine = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
        stagioni = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
        totepisodi = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Views:

```html
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
        titolo = forms.CharField()
        titolo_originale = forms.CharField()
        annoinizio = forms.CharField()
        annofine = forms.CharField()
        stagioni = forms.CharField()
        totepisodi = forms.CharField()

def  nuovaserie(request):
       if request.method == 'POST':
         form=ContactForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
           titolo = request.POST.get('titolo','')
           titolo_originale = request.POST.get('titolo_originale','')
           annoinizio = request.POST.get('annoinizio','')
           annofine = request.POST.get('annofine','')
           stagioni = request.POST.get('stagioni','')
           totepisodi = request.POST.get('totepisodi','')
                                
           cont_obj= Tvserie.objects.create(titolo = titolo, titolo_originale = titolo_originale, annoinizio = annoinizio, annofine = annofine, stagioni = stagioni, totepisodi = totepisodi)
           cont_obj.save()
                        
           return HttpResponseRedirect('/risultatonuovaserie/')
       else:
         form=ContactForm()
         return render(request , 'NuovaSerie.html', {'form': form})
```

Templates:

```html
<form action="/nuovaserie/" method="POST">
  <table border=1>
    <tr>
      <td><label>Titolo*:</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="titolo" value="{{titolo}}"></td>
      <td><label>Titolo originale*:</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="titolo_originale" value="{{titolo_originale}}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label>Anno inizio:</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="annoinizio" value="{{annoinizio}}"></td>
   <td><label>Anno fine:</label></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="annofine" value="{{annofine}}"></td>
    </tr>
      <td><label>stagioni:</label></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="stagioni" value="{{stagioni}}"></td>
   <td><label>totepisodi:</label></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="totepisodi" value="{{totepisodi}}"></td>
    <tr>        
   <td colspan="4"><center><input type="submit" value="Invia"></center></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking to pass the argument 'required=False' for each attribute in your form you don't want to be required.  See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#required.